My python script cannot find the link to click using Selenium. How do I fix it?
I have this script that scrapes contacts from a site and sends it to a csv file. The only problem is that once it enters the site and logs in, it cannot find the link-id to click even though I specified it. I get a timeout error in the line that specifies to find the link. How do I fix it?
Part of the script that logs in and searches for the button:
### Download new version of ChromeDriver into same folder
driver_path = "C:/Users/owner/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service = ChromeService(executable_path=driver_path)
#options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.get(('https://www.editorialmanager.com/ijrm/default1.aspx'))
driver.get(("https://www.editorialmanager.com/ijrm/default1.aspx"))

sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
# FINDING an input:
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/iframe")
)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="passwordTextbox"]').send_keys(password)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emLoginButtonsDiv"]/input[3]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
sleep(5)

# ### Going to the Search People Page
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]'))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
##wait.until(
##    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_Folders_SearchPeople"]'))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lnkSearchPeople')))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'lnkSearchPeople'))).click()
sleep(3)

The button as it appears in the HTML inspector:


Your locator is incorrect. In the HTML it shows the attribute link-id not the id.
So By.ID will not work here.
Go with CSS or xpath selector
(By.XPATH,//*[@link-id = 'lnkSearchPeople'])
(By.CSS,[link-id = 'lnkSearchPeople'])

